# Laravel Forget password Validation note not showing in server

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 8 with the boiler plate authentication. The forget password is working as expected locally but when i push in the server, eventhough the reset link is sent to the mail the confirmation page is not shown. Also, by putting incorrect email the message "We can't find a user with that email address" is not shown in the serve, but it is showing in local environment. Any Idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you setting your .htaccess file on server?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# That was ONLY to protect you from 500 errors
# if your server did not have mod_rewrite enabled

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
# NOT needed unless you're using mod_alias to redirect

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
# Direct all requests to /public folder

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we are using nginx server, any idea with that